# UIView rounded corners breaks when animate view height changing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableview cell with rounded views. When i animate cell height changing it is break rounded corners and restore its when animation is complete.

All layout build with AutoLayout.

Corners rounding code:

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
view.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

View height changed automatically when I change cell height.

How to still rounded corners while view change size?

Comment: GIF about problem https://imgur.com/a/FFNucfp

Comment: I don't see any breakage in your gif. The corners stay rounded the entire time thruout the animation.

Comment: When top cell deselecting bottom corners not rounded

Comment: No, sorry, I don't get it. Plus, you've supplied no code, so it would be impossible to reproduce.

Comment: @Artem - you're changing your cell height... that's fine when it's "growing" as your view catches-up to it, but when "shrinking" the cell bottom clips the bottom portion of the rounded view. You want to use auto-layout so when you increase or decrease the height of the rounded view the cell height automatically increases / decreases (or fix the order of sizing while animating the height change).

Comment: @DonMag Can you explain possible ways to fix it?

Comment: @Artem - as **matt** says, you've supplied no code, so it's not clear what you are currently doing. You say *"View height changed automatically when I change cell height"* -- which leads me to believe you are explicitly setting the cell height, instead of allowing the cell ***content*** to determine the height.

Comment: I tried two realizations:
1: by allow AutoLayout determine content height and change view hieght
2: calculate content height and provide it via heightForRow

In both realizations rounded corners at bottom break

It is not depend of animation speed. Which code I need to provide for explain problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a `backgroundColor` on the `contentView` of your `UITableViewCell`s and you will see that the `cornerRadius` is not actually being broken. The height change of the cell is animating faster than your view is, and it's creating a "clipping" effect.

Comment: Ok, I think it is true, but how I can increase animation duration of height change of the cell?

Comment: I think what you want is for the height of the cell to be dependent on the height of the cell's content, or "dynamic". That way, your cell will change size as the content does and they should remain in sync.